# Liquibase upgrade issue with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, grails, liquibase

I am having problem in upgrading with liquibase. I have an application jbilling-community-4.1.1.

I want to migrate data from jbilling-community3.1.0 to jbilling-community4.1.1 but when I run this command

```
grails upgrade-db -user=root -pass=root -db=jbilling_test -dbVersion=3.2 -url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jbilling_test"
```

It gives this error

```
Error executing script UpgradeDb: : liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL 
CREATE TABLE public.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BIT(1) NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime NULL, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255) NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID)): 
Unknown database 'public' (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

`upgrade-db` is a script which upgrade the database. I have upgrade it using postGres which is default database for jbilling but they say that it can be run with mysql to. But I am getting this exception and it is related to `liquibase` so posting here.

Comment: I have no clue of grails but are you sure you are using the right command line options? The documentation of the grails liquibase plugin has different options: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/ref/Update%20Scripts/dbm-update.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add property -schema=jbilling_test in your command.

Answer (score -1):

try this

`grails upgrade-db -user=root -pass=root -db=jbilling_test -dbVersion=3.2 -url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jbilling_test" -schema=jbilling`

make sure you upgrade 3.0 to 3.1 and then 3.2 and so on